# json web token support in WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2

Hi I am new bee to WS02 identity server and I just want to know that is there any support for Json Web Token (JWT) in the WSO2 identity manager. Is there any possibility by which we can convert SAML2.0 tokens to JWT(Json Web Token)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we use JWTs in three occasions.

1. We return a JWT with user claims at the OAuth 2.0 token validation endpoint.
2. We return a JWT when using OpenID Connect, this is the OpenID Connect IDToken.
3. We can return a JWT as the user info endpoint response in OpenID Connect. But by default we return a JSON instead a JWT.

Yes, you can present a SAML 2.0 token to the IS and get its claims over the ID Token. But this is valid only for the OAuth SAML 2.0 Grant Type.

Comment: Thanks Suresh for your reply just want to know that after the successful authentication/authorization can I return Json Web Token instead SAML 2.0 from the WS02 identity server if yes then can you please share a link explains the same scenario ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement?

Comment: I want to achieve SSO in my java mobile application. For this i have come up with a work flow and i want to use WSO2 for achieving this.

Comment: use OAuth 2.0 with the wso2 identity server. This documentation would be a good start for you. http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/OAuth+2.0+Playground+with+WSO2+Identity+Server . Look at the source code for the step 17. There in the code, it sends the access token to the token validation endpoint and gets the validation response. In that response you can get a JWT.

Comment: I want to achieve SSO in my java mobile application. For this i have come up with a work flow 

and i want to use WSO2 for achieving this.

1. I have a Java Application which needs to communicate to OAuth server of WSO2.
2. OAuth server should redirect to another instance of WSO2 which acts as RP-STS.

Comment: 3. RP-STS should do Home Realm Discovery(HRD) and receive token from different IDP (Identity 

Providers) and token format can be SAML or Json Web Token.

Comment: 4. RP-STS should return a JWT token to OAuth server with claims.
So my main concern is what are the channels (WS-Fed , WS-Trust or OAuth) and Tokens format (SAML or Json Web Tokens) supported to achieve step 2 and 3.

Comment: Okay, this is the solution I can provide you. App redirects the user for the WSO2 IS SAML 2.0 SSO IDP and retrieves the SAML 2.0 token, Then with this SAML token, the user is again redirected by the app to the WSO2 IS OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server using the OAuth 2.0 SAML Grant Type. Then in return the app gets the IDToken from the WSO2 IS OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server. Remember to use the scop "openid" when using the SAML Grant. The IDToken is a JWT containing user claims of the user.

Comment: Thanks Suresh so once I get coarsed grained claims in the form of Json Web Token I want to setup a seprate instance of XACML3.0 engine which acts as a fined grained claims authorization. So where I can introduce this XACML engine according to the flow you proposed.

Comment: what is your XAXML PEP going to be ?

Comment: PEP is our JAVA application . We are planning to use XACML engine as  PDP.

Comment: Thanks Suresh just want to know how the user is going to enter credentials in the login screen as the scenario proposed by you using WSO2 ?

Comment: that should happened at the WSO2 Identity Server SAML 2.0 loging page.

Comment: Is it possible for the user to login in his own identity provider page once the Home Realm Discovery done from WSO2 end ?

Comment: hi suresh can we implement federation in WSO2 using federation plugin. I have one federation plugin by which we can implement ws-federation. Can you please take a look at Apache CXF plugin and please suggest something.